# Como hacer un if correcto dentro de un foreach?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

Tengo un input de tipo texto ahí se introduce un id para verificar si este exististe o no.

```
list.forEach(function(a) {
    if (b == a["id"]) {
        g["setstatus"](true, a["id"], f);
        return c(true)
        alert("Correcto!");
    }
    g["setstatus"](false, null, f);
    return c(false)
});
```

Los datos que recibo dentro del foreach es de tipo JSON

```
[
  {"id":2,"email":"user3@gmail.com","name":"User example 3","c":false},
  {"id":2,"email":"user2@gmail.com","name":"User example 2","c":false},
  {"id":1,"email":"user1@gmail.com","name":"User Example 1","c":false}
]
```

El problema es al momento de verificar `b == a["id"]`, en este caso b es la variable que recibe el valor del usuario.

Cuando pongo 3 o 2 en el input esta no reconoce, pero cuando pongo 1 recién reconoce, se que es por el foreach, También realicé de esta manera:

```
a.forEach(function(a) {
    if (b == a["id"]) {
        g["setstatus"](true, a["id"], f);
        alert("Correcto!");
        return c(true)
    }

});
g["setstatus"](false, null, f);
return c(false)
```

Pero lastimosamente tampoco me funcionó.

Comment: No comprendo bien qué es lo que quieres realizar con tu programa?

Comment: ¿Cuál es el valor de b?

Comment: Al momento de comprar b == a["id"] esta se tiene que activar "g["setstatus"](true, a["id"], f);
        return c(true)", el problema es con el foreach ya que esta recorriendo todos los registros y solo me reconoce el ID = 1 y no los demas 2 o 3.

Comment: El valor de B llega de un formulario INPUT.

Comment: @JhosselinGiménez de la sentencia dentro del foreach me parece correcto  que solo haga el `g["setstatus"](true, a["id"], f); return c(true)` en la primera iteración si `b = 1`. Si `b = 2` debería hacer el setStatus en la segunda iteración, etc.

Comment: No le entiendo muy bien, me explica por favor? :)

Comment: Cuidado que el return interrumpe la función dentro del foreach y no la función que llamó al foreach

Comment: Es por la condición dentro del foreach @JhosselinGiménez, creo que nos sería más simple ayudarte si nos planteas que debería hacer tu código, por ejemplo: qué hace la función g['setstatus']?

Comment: Bueno es algo simple dentro del foreach hay un if si el if es correcto entonces debe romperse todo y mostrar una alerta "aceptado".

Comment: FUNCIONA TODO BIEN SOLO CON EL PRIMER ID Y NO CON LOS OTROS, ES DECIR SI EL USUARIO INGRESA 3 O 2 NO FUNCIONA PERO SI INGRESA 1 SI FUNCIONA.

Comment: Mira: cuando ingreso 2 = http://prntscr.com/faxpbf y cuando ingreso 1 si lo reconoce = http://prntscr.com/faxpo0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

La razón por la cuál tu sentencia está fallando para valores dónde `b!=1` es porque tu condición no hace ningún break al foreach y por lo tanto siempre evaluará los otros valores(que estarían dando falso)

Ejemplo: b=3

```
# primer ciclo, a = {"id":3,"email":"user3@gmail.com","name":"User example 3","c":false}
# se activa el botón porque la sentencia b = a["id"], se cumple

# segundo ciclo, a = {"id":2,"email":"user2@gmail.com","name":"User example 2","c":false}
# se desactiva el botón porque la sentencia deja de cumplirse.
```

La razón por la que con `b=1` siempre queda activado es debido a que es el último item en tu lista y por lo tanto no existe un siguiente que desactive el botón.

Una posible solución sería dejar de usar el foreach y en su lugar hacer:

```
var exist = list.some(function(a) {
  return b == a["id"]; // or b == a.id;
});

if(exist) {
  g["setstatus"](true, a["id"], f);
  alert("Correcto!");
}
```

Puedes ver más sobre el uso de `some` [aquí](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some?v=control)

Comment: Gracias, me funcionó!!!

Comment: solo una cosa que creo me hizo falta en la condición, en caso que el `if(exist)` de false, debería existir un `else` con `g["setstatus"](false, null, f);` o algo parecido

Comment: Si, ya lo agregué, muchas gracias Learnercys!